# What culture code should I use for Pinyin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cjk, currentuiculture

**My Question**

If you want to display Pinyin for Chinese-speaking users, in what "resource file" would you store the Pinyin translation?

Since Pinyin is NOT a "language" per se, but a Latin representation of Chinese characters, it does NOT have a culture code in .NET.

My guess is that we probably need to use the applicable "zh-" (Chinese) cultures and simply place the latin character Pinyin translation inside those resource files.

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but all the different culture stuff is scrambling my brain!!

**Background**

We're finally getting around to Internationalization of our Web sites.  We're handling most of the "Western" cultures okay now (Latin alphabet: "es", "fr", "de") and the different date/number formats.  However, the ideogram-based writing systems like Chinese are a challenge due to various legacy systems not handling Unicode.  As a short-term workaround, our business area decided to use Pinyin for Chinese speaking users.

So... the business area asked me to "just add a Pinyin resource file" to the site.

Comment: have you considered making your own custom culture? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx

Comment: I had thought about doing a custom culture, but it somehow felt... "dirty"  ;-)    Plus, wouldn't that prevent me from ever using the browser's setting for language?  Maybe that isn't a good idea anyway, and we should always let the user "choose" the language on the site somehow?

Comment: You should always let the user be able to override whatever setting you might have chosen for them based on their browser. Its good practice to direct users into the language supported by the browser, but consider yourself sitting with your friends laptop, having no option to revert to ie. English without starting to do changes to his browsers settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft culture code is in the format of :

```
"language-country"
```

So, take Chinese for example.  The code for Chinese is "zh".  However, there are many countries and regions that use Chinese, so we append a country code to the language code.  "zh-cn" stands for Chinese-Mainland China.  Similarly, "zh-tw" represents Chinese for Taiwan.

.Net uses the concept of resource fallback, where resource lookups begins at the level specified and as long as the resource is not found, a less specific resource will be looked at until we get to the default resource.  So ideally, the "zh-cn" resource file should contain only resources that are specific to Mainland China.  All resources that are common to all Chinese speaking countries should reside in the "zh" resource.

So getting to your question, I believe Pinyin is primarily used in mainland China, and since you are using it as a Chinese translation substitute, I would place the Pinyin translations inside the "zh-cn" resource file.

Comment: There actually is no "zh" resource as there is with "en", "es", "fr", etc.   HOWEVER, prompted by your response I found that there *ARE* fallback resource lookups for Chinese. "zh-CHS" is the "Chinese (Simplified)" parent or fallback, and "zh-CHT" is the "Chinese (Traditional)" parent/fallback. See here: http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/LocalizingDOTNet.pdf So thank you, that saves me some potential effort there!!

Comment: Okay, I need to apologize. I've learned since writing my previous comment that some of the online resources I've been using are out of date. I wrote some quick C# code to display all the cultures in NET 4.0, and "zh" *is* a valid "neutral" culture. I also learned that "zh-CHS" and "zh-CHT" are "legacy", and have been replaced by "zh-Hans" and "zh-Hant", respectively.

Comment: And your comment regarding Pinyin, "zh-CN" seems to be good advice.  Although I still don't understand why .NET has that one pointing back to "zh-CHS" as its parent, which is is legacy.  Maybe they're trying to make all the "zh-" legacy except for zh-Hant and zh-Hans eventually??  Anyway, I'm giving you the answer.  **Thanks so much**!

Comment: @BojinLi - You should really update your answer to reflect the findings from your comment. `zh-CH` doesn't work at all, what worked for me was `zh-Hans`.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** `zh-Latn-pinyin`, `zh-Latn-CN-pinyin`, `cmn-Latn-pinyin` would all be valid.

The [IANA Language Subtag Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) defines the variant subtag `pinyin`, to be used with prefix `zh-Latn` for Chinese (and `bo-Latn` for Tibetan).

W3C's recommendation:

> Check the context and ordering for variant subtags. Most variant
> subtag records in the registry have one or more `Prefix` fields. The
> prefixes indicate with which subtags it is usually appropriate to use
> this variant. For example, **`pinyin` should generally be used in a
> language tag that also contains either the subtags `zh` and `Latn` or the
> subtags `bo` and `Latn`**, since the entry for `pinyin` contains the
> following:
>
> ```
> Prefix: zh-Latn
> Prefix: bo-Latn
> ```
>
> If you have a good reason, you could
> use a variant subtag with different subtags, eg. `cmn-Latn-pinyin` would
> be a perfectly legal way to say Mandarin Chinese written with pinyin.
>
> Although `zh`, `bo` and `Latn` are specified, this is a minimum requirement.
> **It is also possible to include other subtags, such as a region subtag,
> in the language tag (where appropriate), eg. `zh-Latn-CN-pinyin`.**
>
> https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags#variants